# With R Markdown or Quarto can I embed a comment in HTML output?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I would like to add "hidden" text (the GitHub repo and code file name) to a report that is rendered to HTML with R Markdown (or Quarto).  Is there an easy way to save some text information so it will show up when I inspect a document in a browser but the text will not show for the casual consumer of the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Quarto (and similar for R Markdown):

```
---
format: html
---

This is some text.

<!-- This will be displayed in the page source code but not in the output. -->
```